# Find Mistake: Independence of two Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Assume we have a black and a red cube with 6 sides. We definite two  events A = "the black dice shows 5", B = "The product of the number of pips is a prime number". We roll the dice. So $P[A] = \frac{1}{6}$ and $P[B] = \frac{1}{6}$ right ? Now i want to check, if  A and B are independent. So $P[A \cap B] = \frac{1}{36} = \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{6} = P[A]P[B]$ so A and B are independent. My instincts tell me the events are dependent. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Looks right.  Hard to have intuition about things like this.

Comment: What do you mean with "the number of pips" ?

Comment: "*My instincts tell me the events are dependent.  Where is my mistake?*"  Your mistake is in being too trusting of your instincts.  This is a fine example of a pair of independent events whose independence may be counterintuitive.

Comment: @Peter a six sided die is commonly made with a number of small colored circular indentations called "pips."  The numerical result of throwing a die is the number of visible pips on the upward showing face.  Worded another way, it is the numerical result that the die shows.

Comment: I would say that "independence" intuitively means that one event has no influence on another.  When we make a mathematically precise definition however, we capture other cases that don't conform to our original intuition.

Comment: @JMoravitz So , $B$ means that one of the dices shows $1$ and the other $2,3$ or $5$ ?

Comment: "The product of the number of pips is a prime number" is the event $\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,1),(3,1),(5,1)\}$

Comment: @Peter yes, precisely.  And it so happens that "The black die shows a $5$" is independent of "The product of the results of the dice is prime" but of course you have "The black die shows a 6" is clearly dependent of "The product of the results of the dice is prime."  In several other early examples with dice, you can replace the number that the black die shows with any other number and the result of whether it is dependent or independent would have stayed the same.  That is not the case for this example.

Comment: You might find it instructive to read Chapter 1, Section 6, titled *Independence and "Independence"* from Mark Kac's [Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis, and Number Theory](http://www.gibbs.if.usp.br/~marchett/estocastica/MarkKac-Statistical-Independence.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

$B$, "The product of the number of pips is a prime number", is the event $\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,1),(3,1),{\bf(5,1)}\}$

So $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ is clearly $1/6$.

The weighted ratio of outcomes in $A\cap B$ to $B$ equals the weighted ratio of outcomes in $A$ to $\Omega$ (the outcome set).

That is all that is required for independence.

The notion that "independent events don't influence each other" is not *too* misleading.   It is just that our judgement on whether this is the case is not very reliable.   Our instincts can be way off.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake, probably, is that you're forgetting the fact that both the dice are rolled SIMULTANEOUSLY.

This problem is somewhat analogous to another problem where two dice are rolled simultaneously, and the number appearing on the first die is independent of the number appearing on the second one.